# When converting image to video in C# how can I increase the length (runtime) of the video?

Tags: c#, windows, image, video, converters

I'm using the `Accord.Extensions.Imaging` library. The code below successfully converts png files with specified dimensions (729, 674) placed in the `bin > Debug > Images` folder and puts the converted video file in `bin > Debug` folder but the length of the video is 0 seconds. I know it worked because I see the image for a split seconds when playing the video file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Accord.Extensions.Imaging;

namespace Image_To_Video_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            makeAvi("images", "video.avi");

        }

        public static void makeAvi(string imageInputfolderName, string outVideoFileName, float fps = 12.0f, string imgSearchPattern = "*.png")
        {   // reads all images in folder 
            VideoWriter w = new VideoWriter(outVideoFileName,
                new Accord.Extensions.Size(729, 674), fps, true, VideoCodec.MotionJpeg);
            Accord.Extensions.Imaging.ImageDirectoryReader ir =
                new ImageDirectoryReader(imageInputfolderName, imgSearchPattern);            

            while (ir.Position < ir.Length)
            {
                IImage i = ir.Read();
                w.Write(i);
            }
            w.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each image consumes one frame. So you can lower the value of (Frame Per Second) fps. Which is 12 in your current code to 1 for example. in that case your images will display 1 second each.

Comment: Thanks! I want to use just one image and convert it to a ~2min video, since it's not possible to use less than one fps in the code I just duplicated the image multiple times in the folder and it worked, that's not the best workaround but it works. Do you know how to do it properly via code?

Comment: Instead of duplicating it in folder multiple times you can use one image in folder and just write it multiple times with w.Write(i); for getting 2 minute video you need to write it 120 times with frame rate 1

Comment: Great, much appreciated!